# Sql rollup sort by datename

Tags: sql, sorting, rollup

I have an example Northwind query where I am using rollup up DATEPART for Date Year & DATENAME for Month name. How can I sort the month in chronological order with each year for each customer? Thanks in advance.

I have tried order by the DATEPART but fail to achieve the required result

```sql
    SELECT c.CompanyName
    ,DATEPART(YYYY,o.orderdate) 'Yr'
    ,DATENAME(MM,o.orderdate) 'Mth'
    ,COUNT(o.OrderID) 'Orders'
    FROM Orders o
    INNER JOIN Customers c 
    ON o.customerid = c.CustomerID
    GROUP BY ROLLUP (c.CompanyName,
    DATEPART(YYYY,o.orderdate),DATENAME(MM,o.orderdate))
```

the result is:

| CompanyName | Yr | Mth | Orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alfreds Futterkiste | 1997 | August | 1 |
| Alfreds Futterkiste | 1997 | October | 2 |
| Alfreds Futterkiste | 1997 | NULL | 3 |
| Alfreds Futterkiste | 1998 | April | 1 |
| Alfreds Futterkiste | 1998 | January | 1 |
| Alfreds Futterkiste | 1998 | March | 1 |
| Alfreds Futterkiste | 1998 | NULL | 3 |
| ... ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Wolski Zajazd | 1996 | December | 1 |
| Wolski Zajazd | 1996 | NULL | 1 |
| Wolski Zajazd | 1997 | December | 1 |
| Wolski Zajazd | 1997 | July | 1 |
| Wolski Zajazd | 1997 | NULL | 2 |
| Wolski Zajazd | 1998 | April | 2 |
| Wolski Zajazd | 1998 | February | 2 |
| Wolski Zajazd | 1998 | NULL | 4 |
| Wolski Zajazd | NULL | NULL | 7 |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | 829 |

Comment: Can you use numeric months instead of the full month name - they will naturally sort?

Comment: It's probably more natural and possibly an optimization to group by month number or truncated date at the second level and then convert the displayed output at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This gives the same query but sorted by year and month.  It can be used as the input for a CTE - common table expression.  The select can use a case statement convert the numeric month to a alpha month.

```
-- This gives the results with numeric year and month sorted
SELECT 
    c.CompanyName,
    YEAR(o.orderdate) as YearNo,
    MONTH(MM,o.orderdate) as MonthNo,
    COUNT(o.OrderID) OrderTotal
FROM 
    Orders o
INNER JOIN 
    Customers c 
ON 
    o.customerid = c.CustomerID
GROUP BY ROLLUP 
   (c.CompanyName, Year(o.orderdate), Month(o.orderdate))
ORDER BY
   2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    CompanyName,
    year(Orderdate) as Yr,
    datename(month, Orderdate) as Mnth,
    count(*) OrderTotal
from T
group by rollup 
   (CompanyName, year(Orderdate), datename(month, OrderDate))
order by
    grouping(CompanyName), CompanyName,
    grouping(year(Orderdate)), year(OrderDate),
    grouping(datename(month, Orderdate)), min(OrderDate);
```

There's probably a good case to be made that grouping on either the month number or the truncated month would make more sense. Nonetheless, you can still refer to a date aggregrate (like `min(OrderDate)` to refer back to an actual date value within that set of dates which will then sort in the proper order.

https://dbfiddle.uk/vsNEr83n